# Optimization of a T-SQL Query with probability for selection

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table with entries from which two entries are supposed to be selected. The probability of some entries to be selected should be higher than the probability of others.

Currently I solve this with `UNION ALL` accordingly I select once all entries and then again the entries which should have a higher probability. From this merged table I select then after the call of `ORDER BY NEWID()` for mixing with `TOP 2` two entries.

```
SELECT TOP 2 EMail 
FROM (
   SELECT EMail 
   FROM dbo.Benutzer 
   UNION ALL 
   SELECT EMail 
   FROM dbo.Benutzer 
   WHERE param1 = 1 
   UNION ALL 
   SELECT EMail 
   FROM dbo.Benutzer 
   WHERE param2 = 1
) AS EMail 
ORDER BY NEWID();
```

Example table:

```
EMail           param1      param2
______________|_________|___________
Test@test.com |0        | 0             -> probability is 1 (normal)
Test1@test.com|1        | 0             -> probability is 2 (higher than 1)
Test2@test.com|1        | 0             -> probability is 2 (higher than 1)
Test3@test.com|1        | 1             -> probability is 3 (higher than 1 and 2)
Test4@test.com|1        | 0             -> probability is 2 (higher than 1)
Test5@test.com|1        | 0             -> probability is 2 (higher than 1)
```

so if I make a select from this table and shuffle it before that, that with each new select different data comes out, the probability should be based on this table. So how likely it is that this entry comes up.

Always two different users should come out. e.g. Test3 and Test4. However, also Test unf Test3 so it should be only a probability.

However, this query is not performat. How can this problem be solved in a performant way?

Comment: This doesn't sound like it should be T-SQL logic, if I am honest, but application logic.

Comment: What do you mean by that?

Comment: Where is query to optimize?

Comment: *"What do you mean by that? "* That the logic of the *randomly weighted* selection should be application logic, not T-SQL. I'm not sure how to elaborate that more. Do it in the application.

Comment: I have added the current query

Comment: Sometimes both email will be the same.  Is it ok?

Comment: @Serg no I always need two different users. I then check on the application side that the two entries are not identical, e.g. Test2 and Test2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Updated answer:**

It seems that you want to randomly choose one row per e-mail with higher probabilty. In this situation you need to number the rows for each different e-mail:

```
SELECT *
INTO Benutzer
FROM (VALUES
   ('Test@test.com',  0, 0),             
   ('Test1@test.com', 1, 0),             
   ('Test2@test.com', 1, 0),             
   ('Test3@test.com', 1, 1),             
   ('Test4@test.com', 1, 0),             
   ('Test5@test.com', 1, 0)              
) v (EMail, param1, param2)

SELECT TOP 2 Email
FROM (
   SELECT b.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY b.Email ORDER BY a.probability DESC) AS rn
   FROM Benutzer b
   CROSS APPLY (VALUES
      (1), -- normal probability
      (
      1 + 
      CASE WHEN param1 = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END + 
      CASE WHEN param2 = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
      )    -- calculated probability
   ) a (probability)
) t
WHERE t.rn = 1
ORDER BY NEWID()
```

Finally, you may try to number the rows randomly:

```
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY b.Email ORDER BY NEWID()) AS rn
```

**Original answer:**

If I understand the question correctly, you simply need to calculate the probability for each row based on desired conditions:

```
SELECT TOP 2 EMail
FROM (VALUES
   ('Test@test.com',  0, 0),             
   ('Test1@test.com', 1, 0),             
   ('Test2@test.com', 1, 0),             
   ('Test3@test.com', 1, 1),             
   ('Test4@test.com', 1, 0),             
   ('Test5@test.com', 1, 0)              
) Benutzer (EMail, param1, param2)
ORDER BY 
   (
   1 +
   CASE WHEN param1 = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
   CASE WHEN param2 = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
   ) DESC,
   NEWID()
```

An important note (based on the @GordonLinoff's comment) - if `NEWID()` is the first order expression, the second order by expression is ignored, so I placed `NEWID()` as second order expression (and this was the first version of the answer). But, in this case, the rows are **not** returned randomly.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I would like then that the TOP 2 always outputs different entries therefore the ORDER BY NEWID(). These two entries should be based on the priority

Comment: @Lukas, can you post sample data and expected results? `ORDER BY NEWID()` orders the rows randomly, not by probability. If you need to select two random rows from all rows, ordered by `probablitiy`, add `NEWID()` in the `ORDER BY` clause.

Comment: Thanks for your solution. This seems to be the right way. But now the user test3 is always on place one. I want that the probability for the user Test3 is higher, but the user Test can also be on place one.
Always two different users should come out. e.g. Test3 and Test4. However, also Test unf Test3 so it should be only a probability

Comment: @Lukas, does switching the `ORDER BY` parts (`NEWID()` first)  return the expected results?

Comment: @Lukas . . .  The second `order by` key is ignored.  To me, this seems like it just returns random rows and hence does **not** answer your question.

Comment: @Gordon Linoff do you have a working Solution?

Comment: @Zhorov do you Considered That?

Comment: @Lukas, yes, and to be honest, I need to rethink the answer again. But, with your current approach (using `UNION ALL`), you get all the rows from the table and then some of the rows under condition. It;s possible to get two rows for the same e-mail and this is contrary to your requirement (_always two different users should come out_).

Comment: @Zhorov yes, the thing with same value is a problem. I solve that currently on application side by checking that there and if necessary execute the whole thing again until two different values are returned. Unfortunately, this is all very performance-heavy. About a revised answer from you I would be very happy

Comment: @Lukas, the answer is updated (... although I'm still not sure if this is the expected result).

Comment: @Zhorov That was one of your ideas yesterday. But now the user Test3 is always given first place.

Comment: @Lukas, no, see the `Updated answer` section. The rows are returned randomly.

Comment: @Zhorov sorry, I didn't see that. Your new answer seems to work very well. Thanks for the effort

Comment: Looks like it still returns random rows evenly distributed.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using a tally table and ROW_NUMBER() functions.
The Tally table is used to create the correct number of duplicate rows for each row based upon probability as given.
The ROW_NUMBER() function creates to row numbers one based upon a sort order of NewId() - this is RN, the other is based upon the ordering within an email address - this is RNK.

We want to select 2 rows ordered by RN, but use RNK = 1 to ensure we don't receive duplicates.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/0d6cc0/1)

**MS SQL Server 2017 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE Benutzer
(
    Email VARCHAR(30),
    Param1 Int,
    Param2 Int
);

INSERT INTO Benutzer
VALUES
       ('Test@test.com',  0, 0),       -- probability 1      
       ('Test1@test.com', 1, 0),       -- probability 2      
       ('Test2@test.com', 1, 0),       -- probability 2      
       ('Test3@test.com', 1, 1),       -- probability 3      
       ('Test4@test.com', 1, 0),       -- probability 2      
       ('Test5@test.com', 1, 0)        -- probability 2
```

**Query 1**:

```
WITH Tally As
(
    SELECT *
    FROM (VALUES
        (1),             
        (2),             
        (3)          
        ) Tally (Num)
),
Results AS
(
    SELECT Email, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER By NewId()) AS RN,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PArtition BY Email ORDER BY PAram1) As Rnk
    FROM Benutzer
    INNER JOIN Tally
        ON TAlly.Num <= 1 + Param1 + Param2
)
SELECT TOP 2 Email
FROM Results
WHERE Results.Rnk =1
ORDER BY RN
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/0d6cc0/1/0)**:

```
|          Email |
|----------------|
| Test2@test.com |
| Test5@test.com |
```

Comment: thank you for your very detailed answer. I have looked at this so far and it seems to work. I just do not quite understand how the probability is taken into account here. For example that Test3 has a two times higher probability to be output than the user test.

Comment: If you look at the join to the Tally table, when Param1 & Param2 both equal 1 the join condition Tally.Num <= 1 + Param1 + Param2 will join to Tally rows 1, 2 & 3 thus 3 rows will be presented from the Results CTE. If Param1 & Param2 equal 0 only 1 row will be output when Tally.Num = 1

Answer (score 0):

Taking the probability into account. Using a recursion because the next step depends on the result of the previous one, ignore new random index if it points to the same range.

```
   with weighted as (
      -- weight = f (param1, param2) , using 1 + param1 + param2 here
      select Email, param1, param2, count(*) * (1 + param1 + param2) n
      from Benutzer
      group by Email, param1, param2
   ), ranges as (
     --  a range width = weight
     select Email, sum(n) over(order by Email)- n + 1 n1, sum(n) over(order by Email) n2, sum(n) over() sn
     from weighted
   ), h as (
     select 1 level, t2.*, ABS(CHECKSUM(NewId())) r
         -- , @rnd  % t2.sn + 1  k
     from ranges t2 
     where (@rnd  % t2.sn + 1) between t2.n1 and t2.n2 

     union all
     -- try next random index till the next row is a new one
     select case when t2.Email = h.Email then level else level + 1 end
         , t2.* , ABS(CHECKSUM(NewId()))
         -- ,  r % t2.sn + 1
     from ranges t2 
     join h on r % t2.sn + 1  between t2.n1 and t2.n2 
     where level <=1
   )
   -- take one row from every level
   select top(1) with ties Email, @cnt
   from h
   order by row_number() over(partition by level order by newid());
```

See test [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=d2468df035fe5343dea27cbde18ea1d7)

500 runs statistics:

```
Email   n   p
Test@test.com   68  6.800000000000
Test1@test.com  179 17.900000000000
Test2@test.com  159 15.900000000000
Test3@test.com  246 24.600000000000
Test4@test.com  180 18.000000000000
Test5@test.com  168 16.800000000000
```

Not ideal but close.

Answer (score 0):

**What's the main problem?**

When using `ORDER BY NEWID()` approach the `ORDER BY` clause will cause all records in the result set be sorted which can be a very expensive operation (can use a lot of disk I/O) when the base table has a big number of records.

**My suggested solution:**

If we add an ID column to the base table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE #T
(
  ID int IDENTITY(1, 3) PRIMARY KEY,
  Email varchar(100),
  Param1 int,
  Param2 int
);
```

Then we can use this query to get the desired result (without duplicated values):

```
WITH RndRange AS
(
    SELECT MIN(ID) RangeStart, MAX(ID) + 2 RangeEnd FROM #T
)
,RndSelector AS
(
    SELECT NULL AS HitID, 0 AS HitCounter, CAST('' AS varchar(100)) AS HitIDList
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 
        NewHitID,
        HitCounter + IIF(HitID IS NULL, 0, 1), 
        CAST(HitIDList + IIF(NewHitID IS NULL, '', CONCAT(NewHitID, ',')) AS varchar(100))
    FROM 
        RndSelector 
    CROSS APPLY
    (
        SELECT ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID()) % (RangeEnd - RangeStart + 1)) + RangeStart AS RndNum FROM RndRange
    ) C
    OUTER APPLY
    (
        SELECT 
            ID AS NewHitID 
        FROM 
            #T 
        WHERE 
            (ID BETWEEN RndNum - 2 AND RndNum) --Added just for performance
            AND
            (RndNum BETWEEN ID AND ID + Param1 + Param2) 
            AND 
            ID NOT IN (SELECT Value FROM string_split(HitIDList, ','))
    ) O
    WHERE 
        HitCounter + IIF(HitID IS NULL, 0, 1) < 2
)
SELECT * FROM #T WHERE ID IN (SELECT HitID FROM RndSelector)
```

**How does it work?**

Suppose we have these records in the table:

```
ID  Email   Param1  Param2
1   User1   1       1
4   User2   1       0
7   User3   0       0
```

Each round the recursive is executed one random int number between 1 and 9 (min ID and max ID + 2) is generated. When the random number is between 1 and 3 then the ID of User1 is selected (hit). If random number is 4 or 5 then User2 is selected and when random number is 6 then nothing is selected so go to the next round. The execution of recursive will continue until 2 different IDs are selected (HitCounter = 2).

And with the help of HitIDList, repeated IDs will not be selected again.

As you see there is no table sort required by using this solution. We just generate a few random numbers and find their related records in which dbms will use index scans to find records. So I expect considerable performance improvement because of reduced I/O operations specially for large tables.

**Answer Updated:**

I added a condition `ID BETWEEN RndNum - 2 AND RndNum` to the query and now it is blazing fast.
Speed test results on a table with 1000000 records:

| Applied Query | Test1 | Test2 | Test3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ORDER BY NEWID() | 477ms | 400ms | 510ms |
| Random generator | 2ms | 3ms | 2ms |

Comment: thanks for your Solution. The Problem i see is that param1 and param2 can change very often for every user so if i understand your solution Right if the value for param1 or param2 changes i need to update the id for all entrys Right?

Comment: @Lukas No, you don't need to update any ID. For example, numbers 1 and 2 and 3 are reserved for User1 forever. When random num is 3 and User1.Param is 1 and User1.Param2 is 1 then the User1 will be selected because ID + Param1 + Param2 is equal 3 for that user. But when Param2 changes to zero then no user is selected because number 3 was reserved for User1 and now ID + Param1 + Param2 is equal 2. So when random num is 3 then no user can be selected and the query will generate another random num trying to select a user again.